# How to populate a location on google map using php?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I'm building something which requires the user to input their location but now I want a way where I can display this location on the google map for better context.

I stored the location data in my MySQL database and want to know if there is a way for me to fetch the data from my database and display them on a map on the frontend.

If this is possible, please guide me?

Comment: in what format is the location? address, city name, lat/lng? There are thousands of examples of populating a map with markers using data from a db here on Stack

Comment: Address and the city. I have them saved in the database already.

Comment: using address and city rather than lat/lng means you will need to geocode each time you need to show the marker ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple ) - whereas if you geocode once and store the lat/lng there will be no such need

Comment: I will do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an example of using the results from a database query and the `geocoding` service for Google Maps perhaps this will give you an idea of what to do. This is untested btw and the sql is an example only - that would need to be modified to suit your db - and any references to `city` and `address` also modified to suit column names.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script async defer src='//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=<APIKEY>&callback=initMap'></script>
    <script>
        var map,geocoder,obj;

        <?php
            $dbhost =   'localhost';
            $dbuser =   'root'; 
            $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
            $dbname =   'xxx';
            $db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

            $sql='select `city`,`address` from `my_table`';
            $res=$db->query( $sql );

            $arr=array();
            while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
                $arr[]=array( 'city'=>urldecode( $rs->city ), 'address'=>urldecode( $rs->address ) );
            }
            $json=json_encode( $arr );

            echo "
            var json={$json};";
        ?>

        function initMap(){
            var centre=new google.maps.LatLng( 56.65, -2.52 );
            var options = {
                zoom: 16,
                center:centre,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            var evtcallback=function(results, status){
                if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ){

                    var _address=results[0].formatted_address;
                    var _location=results[0].geometry.location;
                    var _lat=_location.lat();
                    var _lng=_location.lng();


                    latlng=new google.maps.LatLng( _lat, _lng );

                    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                        position:latlng,
                        title:_address,
                        map:map,
                        draggable:true,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(event){
                        alert('Record lat/lng to db - lat:'+event.latLng.lat()+', lng:'+event.latLng.lng() )
                    }.bind( marker ));
                }
            }

            /* loop through json data from database, geocode each address and add marker to the map */
            for( var n in json ){
                obj=json[n];
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address':obj.address+', '+obj.city }, evtcallback );
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 80vh;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question, as it is, should be closed, as it's too broad and basically just asking for a tutorial. We don't know how OP wants to do things. Why would you answer it with untested (and bad/ugly) code, only based on assumptions?

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Comment: Sorry about that. Nothing personal. It's just not *best practice*, I am sure you would agree on that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can start with it. From the google map [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start), you can build a map by searching a location. And by doing that, You can try it like this.

```
$address = "Duke Rd & Walden Ave, Buffalo"; //address saved from database
$city = "New York"; //city saved from database

$full_address = rawurlencode($address.",".$city);
$apikey = ""; // your google api key

?>
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=<?=$full_address?>&key=<?= $apikey ?>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```